# Make input fields translatable with Polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, polylang

I have recently bought a WP Theme for my bussiness.
I have managed to translate all the theme except one thing.
I use Polylang Plugin to create multilingual posts. I also use a custom POST type 'property'. When i hit the flag button from the right panel the title and the post content wipes and lets me translate it.

Screenshot first [image]

Screenshot second [image]

but when I try to do the same with another field named facts it always overwrites it to the latest string.

Screenshot three [image]

I want this field to act as post title and post content.
Thank you.
Please let me know if you need addditional information or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.Looks like the issue was with Polylang Settings. I had Custom Fields synchronization turned on.. After turning the synch off it look like the problem was solved..